# php originated text and keyboard-written look the same but are 100% different in diff (and MySQL query)

Tags: mysql, text, unicode

I'm debugging a very simple query, which doesn't bring results although those are clearly in the table. While checking the query, I notice that when I manually write the column value, it returns results. But when I take a printed version of the value, it comes back empty. Moreover, even if I put it in a simple diff tool, it shows that while the two words seem identical, they are 100% not.

Example for the both texts that look the same but aren't:
[image]

When I checked in a different diff tool, the copy-pasted (from the back-end printing) got added a red dot, like this:
[image]
No idea what that red dot is, but even then compared to my writing, none of the chars seemed identical to the diff tool.

It seems the diff char is \u200b, which is a zero width space. How do I remove it? How does he enter when not specified?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a null byte or `\0` or vertical tab `\x0B` appended to your data. Using [trim](http://php.net/trim) will remove these kind of characters.

There are some characters that are there but don't have a visible representation.

Comment: Makes sense, but still trim didn't solve the issue. Any chars trim doesn't handle?

Comment: I see this diff in a text to unicode convertor \u200b

Comment: @Noam: Did you try char by char comparison?

Comment: It seems the added char is \u200b but `$str = trim($str, '\u200b');z doesn't seem to remove it

Comment: `json_decode('\u200b')` will generate the zero-width-space character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HEX function to identify which is the problematic character:

```
SELECT HEX(column)
FROM yourtable
```

Football shold be like this (but it depends on the charset used):

```
466F6F7462616C6C
```

but you will probably see some other characters at the end of the string. You can also try to use BINARY:

```
SELECT HEX(BINARY column) FROM yourtable
```

Then you can use UNHEX and REPLACE:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E2808B'), '')
```

Comment: The problem is actually not in the data in the table, it's actually in the data I'm putting in the SELECT WHERE.

Comment: When I do HEX of the column I get 466F756E646572, and when I do the HEX on the where condition text I get 466F756E646572E2808B. Any clue where does that ending arrived from and how I can remove it in MySQL or PHP or JS?